# multiple if statements without else

Tags: java, if-statement

I don't understand why I get a compile error. In my view, this method first evaluates whether n is > 0. When this is the case, then "good" will be assigned to the String object local.  However, if this is not the case, then it will not do anything. Next, the method enters another decision construct. This time, it evaluates whether n <= 0. If so, it will assign "bad" to the String object.

In any of both cases, local should be initialized. However, I get a compile error, and the compiler says it may not be initialized. I do not understand where this is coming from.

Note that I know how to correct the second if by replacing it with else and removing the boolean condition. I just don't understand why in a syntax sense this is incorrect.

```
public class Donkey{
String s1 = "green";

public void generateReport(int n){
    String local;
    if(n > 0)
        local = "good";
    if(n <= 0)
        local = "bad";
    System.out.println(local);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: `var local = n > 0 ? "good" : "bad";`

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/category/halting-problem/ and https://ericlippert.com/category/definite-assignment-2/ if you are interested in some of the theory here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler has no way to 'know' that you've handled all the cases with your `if` statements.

Consider this example (note that the second `if` is just less than):

```
String local;
if(n > 0)
    local = "good";
if(n < 0)
    local = "bad";
```

If `n = 0`, then `local` will not get defined.

The compiler doesn't test your `if` statements to see if they handle all the cases while compiling.

Changing it to `if/else` will fix the error as you mentioned. You can also initialize the variable as other users have pointed out.

Comment: I agree completely. A third choice is to do something like `String local = n > 0 ? "Good" : "Bad"`;

Comment: " The compiler doesn't test your if statements to see if they handle all the cases while compiling. " That sentence was very enlightening. It made more sense to me now, thank you!

Also @EJoshuaS: I am aware of the ternary operator. Thank you for sharing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if `n` is **not greater** than `0` and is not **less or equal** than `0` the var `local` is not initialized. So that is what the compiler is telling you.

You can solve this by initializing the `local` var with something.

```
String local = "";
```

The problem is solved when you use `else` because for the compiler there can be only 2 possible states, the one if the condition is **true** and the other if is not, there is no possible third state because the `else` contemplates all.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your first point. If `n` is initialized, how could it possibly be something other than greater than, less than, or equal to 0?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: You know that, I know that, **the C# compiler does not know that**.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what possible states could have `n`. And it maybe can be set to null somewhere... And that's what the compiler doesn't know. `else` contemplates all of the others states.

Comment: @EJoshuaS: Think about it this way. Suppose you have a program which assigns a value to the local if and only if Goldbach's Conjecture is true. Do you expect the compiler to provide a proof of this famous unproven conjecture, or do you expect the compiler to produce an error?  Presumably you expect it to produce an error. So there is a line between stuff the compiler is expected to know and stuff it does not.  That exactly one branch of an if-else is executed is on the known side. That numbers have this equality property is on the unknown side.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm aware, my main objection was to the way that it was phrased (because it makes it sound like there's *actually* a third choice, which there clearly isn't; the correct answer is basically what you said - that there is no third choice but the compiler doesn't know that).

Comment: @EricLippert It seems like your comments could be posted an answer though, I think that that's a good explanation of why the compiler can't possibly know that. I can think of things that are even nastier than "prove Goldbach's Conjecture" too (which I suppose is why they didn't even try to put it in the compiler) - you could have any number of undecidable or semi-decidable questions in your `if` statement (the Halting Problem leaps to mind).

Comment: There is an infinity number of states. That's what the compiler thinks. But they are not evaluated by those 2 `If`. If you do the same with `n`being a **boolean** and making 2 ifs (one for **false** and other for **true**), it will happend the same.